# SQL Line break based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

After a SELECT I am getting value like this :

```
Basic:           3 Years/36,000 Miles    Drivetrain:           3 Years/36,000 Miles    Corrosion:           6 Years/100,000 Miles    Roadside Assistance:           3 Years/36,000 Miles
```

I want it to split in two columns like :

```
    Text          Value

    Basic        3 Years/36,000 Miles
    Drivetrain   3 Years/36,000 Miles

etc
```

etc.

Note :

`Basic:-----------3 Years/36,000 Miles`    **- Have 11 spaces in between**

`3 Years/36,000 Miles----Drivetrain:`  - **Have 4 spaces  in between**

Comment: What is the schema of your table and can you provide the select statement ?

Comment: `SELECT Text FROM Info` - The data type of Text is `ntext`  - Here this gives one long row which I said with spaces..

Comment: Use http://sqlfiddle.com to post your table and data

Comment: apparently sqlfiddle is down.

Comment: Are the keywords `Basic:`, `Drivetrain:`, `Corrosion:`, `Roadside Assistance:` consistent across all rows? Do you have any ID column on table? How do you distinguish the rows?

Comment: No they are not consistent...What I want is based on the spaces,,divide them in rows

Answer (score 0):

This works fine with your sample, but you'll have to test it against real data to be sure.

```
WITH CTE_StringSplit AS
(
    SELECT CAST(NULL AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS [Text],  CAST(NULL AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS [Value] ,  CAST([Text] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS RemainingText 
    FROM Info
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
      SUBSTRING(RemainingText,0,CHARINDEX('           ',RemainingText))
      ,LTRIM(SUBSTRING(RemainingText,CHARINDEX('           ',RemainingText),CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('    ',LTRIM(SUBSTRING(RemainingText,CHARINDEX('           ',RemainingText),DATALENGTH(RemainingText)))) > 0 THEN CHARINDEX('    ',LTRIM(SUBSTRING(RemainingText,CHARINDEX('           ',RemainingText),DATALENGTH(RemainingText)))) ELSE DATALENGTH(RemainingText) END + 11))
      ,LTRIM(SUBSTRING(RemainingText,11 + CHARINDEX('           ',RemainingText) + CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('    ',LTRIM(SUBSTRING(RemainingText,CHARINDEX('           ',RemainingText),DATALENGTH(RemainingText)))) > 0 THEN CHARINDEX('    ',LTRIM(SUBSTRING(RemainingText,CHARINDEX('           ',RemainingText),DATALENGTH(RemainingText)))) ELSE DATALENGTH(RemainingText) END,DATALENGTH(RemainingText)))
     FROM CTE_StringSplit
     WHERE LEN(RemainingText)>0
)
SELECT [Text],[Value]
FROM CTE_StringSplit
WHERE [Text] IS NOT NULL
```

Please, update question with additional samples if corrections are needed.